# Can RegEx match function parameters that appear in function body?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to make a RegEx that will match arguments in a function body only when these arguments are passed into the function as parameters.

For example, in the following function:

```
function doStuff(foo, bar) {
  var baz = 1 + foo

  return foo + bar + baz
}
```

RegEx should match `foo` and `bar` in the parameter list and in the body of the function.

I tried some lame backreference matching, but I couldn't come no where near solving this problem...

(The RegEx engine that this needs to work with is [Oniguruma](http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/doc/RE.txt))

Comment: I don't think you can do it for an arbitrary number of parameters, because you can't have a variable number of groups to match in backreferences. You can only do it with a fixed number of parameters.

Comment: Because this requires understanding the structure of the code, and because you want to match both parameters and usages, this is beyond regex. There may be a regex solution, but you should consider *parsing* the input (not *matching* it).

Comment: @Bohemian I want to use this regex to teach my text editor, Atom, to differentiate between parameters vs local variables. TextMate, Sublime, and Atom all use the same system for parsing text, which they call `language grammars`, and it relies on regex. It is possible to use a parser in Atom to achieve this, but it wouldn't be the canonical way to do this sort of thing...